# prometheus loop over values of range or instant vector and apply functions

Tags: function, loops, operators, prometheus, promql

Assuming I have a promQL returning a range or an instant vector:
range vector -> `metric[1h]` or instance vector -> `increase(metric[1h])`

Is there a way to convert range into instant vector and/or vice versa? Because many of the math operations/functions are only possible on instant vectors.

If no conversion possible, is there a way to apply a certain operation or function on each of the values of a range vector? E.g. (square of values):

`(7 @1554105600, 5 @1554710400, 2 @1555315200, 12 @1555920000)` becomes

`(49 @1554105600, 25 @1554710400, 4 @1555315200, 144 @1555920000)`

Answer (score 0):

Range selector with `:` can be applied onto result of function.
For example:

```
max_over_time( sqrt(node_cpu_seconds_total)[1m:])
```

Here `[1m:]` is range selector with unspecified resolution. `:` is crucial here because it allows to apply range selector for something other than vector selectors, where simple `[1m]` will produce an error:

> ranges only allowed for vector selectors

Online demo can be seen [here](https://prometheus.demo.do.prometheus.io/graph?g0.expr=node_cpu_seconds_total&g0.tab=1&g0.stacked=0&g0.range_input=5m&g1.expr=max_over_time(sqrt(node_cpu_seconds_total)%5B1m%3A%5D)&g1.tab=1&g1.stacked=0&g1.range_input=5m).